# Non-Linear color interpolation?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

If I have a straight line that mesures from 0 to 1, then I have colorA(255,0,0) at 0 on the line, then at 0.3 I have colorB(20,160,0) then at 1 on the line I have colorC(0,0,0). How could I find the color at 0.7?

Thanks

Comment: The colors along your line don't have a linear distribution.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is called but I'm wondering how to do this interpolation

Comment: how do you know this is linear?

Comment: I'm working on mulitstop gradients

Comment: @Niki, they might be linear in another color-representation (HSV, HSL).  See my answer below.

Comment: You'd fit a parabola through 3 points, y = a*x^2 + b*x + c.  You've got 3 point and 3 unknowns.  Check your high school math book for, say, Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @Patrick HSV, HSL are non-linear spaces and have the same problem with interpolation as non-linear RGB (sRGB typically).  Linear interpolation of gamma compressed values (non-linear) will make a small, but significant error.

Comment: Isn't this just identifying which segment the value is in, and doing linear interpolation on that segment? Since 0.7 is in the segment from 0.3-1, I would do linear interpolation from 0.3-1 for (20,160,0)-(0,0,0), which would result in (9,69,0). You haven't specified what kind of other, non-linear, interpolation you want, so it's difficult to tell what a good result would be.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

*[Elaborating on my comments to Patrick -- it all got a bit out of hand!]*

This is really an interesting question, and one of the reasons it's interesting is that there is no "right" answer. Colour representation and data interpolation can both be done in many different ways. You need to tailor your approach appropriately for your problem domain. Since we haven't been given much *a priori* information about that domain, we can only explore some of the possibilities.

The business of colours muddies the water somewhat, so let's put that aside temporarily and think first about interpolation of simple scalars.

### Excursion into interpolation

Let's say we have some data points like this:

[image: Three points we might want to fit a function to]

What we want to find is what the `y` value on this graph will be at points along the `x` axis other than the ones for which we have known values. That is, we're looking for a function

`y = f(x)`

that passes through these points.

Clearly, there are many different ways we could choose to join the dots. We might just link them up with straight line segments. Or we might want a smooth curve, and that curve could be simple or arbitrarily complicated:

[image: Some possible interpolations]

Here, it's easy to understand where the red lines come from -- we're just drawing straight lines from one known point to the next. The green line also looks sort of reasonable, though we're adding some assumptions about how the curve should behave. The blue line, on the other hand, would be hard to justify on the basis of the data points alone, but there *might* be circumstances where we have reasons to model the system using such a shape -- as we'll see a bit later.

Note also the dotted lines heading off the sides of each curve. These are going *beyond* the known points, which is called **extrapolation** rather than interpolation. This is often a bit more questionable than interpolation. At least when you're going from one known point to another you have some evidence you're headed the right way. Whereas the further you get from the known points, the more likely it is you'll stray from the path. But still, it's a useful technique and it may well make sense.

OK, so the picture is pretty and all, but how do we generate these lines?

We need to find an `f(x)` that will give us the desired `y`. There are many different functions we could use depending on the circumstances, but by far the most common is to use a polynomial function, ie:

```
f(x) = a0 + a1 * x + a2 * x * x + a3 * x * x * x + ....
```

Now, given `N` distinct data points, it is always possible to find a perfectly-fitting curve using a polynomial of degree `N-1` -- a straight line for two points, a parabola for three, a cubic for four, etc -- but unless the data are unusually well-behaved the curve tends to go haywire as the degree goes up. So unless there is a good reason to believe that the data's behaviour is well modelled by higher-degree polynomials, it's usual instead to interpolate the data **piecewise**, fitting a different curve segment between each successive pair of points.

Typically, each segment is modelled as a polynomial of degree **1** or **3**. The former is just a straight line, and is used because it is really easy and requires no information than the two data points themselves. The latter is a **cubic spline** and is used because it is the simplest polynomial that will gives you a smooth transition across each point. However, calculating it is a bit more complex and requires two extra pieces of information for each segment (exactly what those pieces are depends on the particular spline form you use).

Linear interpolation is easy enough to go in one line of code. If our first data point is `(x1, y1)` and our second is `(x2, y2)`, then the linearly-interpolated `y` at any intermediate `x` is:

```
y = y1 + (x - x1) * (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
```

(Variations on this appear in some of the other answers.)

Cubic splines are a bit too involved to go into here, but Google should turn up some decent references. They are arguably overkill in this case anyway, since you only have three points.

### Back to the question

With all that under our belts, let's take a look at the problem as described:

[image: A grey bar with three known colour points]

We have a line (shown here in grey) whose colour is known only at three points, and we're asked to calculate what the colour will be at some other point. Since we don't have any knowledge of how the colorus are distributed, we have to make some assumptions.

One key assumption is that colour changes along the line will be **continuous**, at least to some approximation. Clearly, if the line really looked like this:

[image: Random stripes]

then all that earlier stuff about interpolation would go out the window. We'd have no basis for deciding what colour any part should be and should just give up and go home. Let's assume that's not the case and we have something to interpolate.

The known colours are specified as **RGB**. In this representation, each channel is a separate scalar value and we can choose to treat it as completely independent of the others. So, one perfectly reasonable approach would be to do a piecewise linear interpolation of each channel and then recombine the results.

Doing so gives us something like this:

[image: Piecewise linear interpolation in RGB]

This is fine as far as it goes, but there are aspects of the result we might not like. One is that the transition from red to green passes through a pretty murky grey-brown. Another is that the green peak at 0.3 is a bit sharp.

It's important to note that, in the absence of a more comprehensive specification, these are really just **aesthetic** concerns. Our *technique* is perfectly sound, but it isn't giving quite the sort of results we might want. This sort of thing depends on our specific problem domain, and ultimately it's all a matter of choice.

Since we have just three data points -- and since Hans Passant suggested it -- perhaps we could instead try fitting a parabola to model the whole curve on each channel? It's true we don't have any reason to think that this is a *good* model, but it doesn't hurt to try:

[image: Quadratic interpolation in RGB]

The differences between this gradient and the last one are instructive. The quadratic has smoothed things out, but has also overshot dramatically. Remember, the green channel both starts and ends at 0. A parabola is symmetrical, so its maximum has to be in the middle. The only way it can fit a green rise towards 0.3 is by continuing to rise all the way to 0.5. (There's a similar effect in the red channel, but it's less obvious because in this case it's an undershoot and the value is clamped to 0.)

Do we have any evidence that this sort of shape is really there in our colour line? Nope: we've explicitly introduced it via our choice of model. That doesn't invalidate it -- we might have good reasons for wanting it to work that way -- once again it's a matter of choice.

### But what about HSV?

So far we've stuck to the original RGB colour space, but as various people rushed to point out this can be less than ideal for interpolation: colour and intensity are bound together in RGB, so interpolating between two different full-intensity colours typically takes you through some drab low-intensity intermediate.

In **HSV** representation, colour and intensity are on separate dimensions, so we don't get that problem. Why not convert and do the interpolation in that space instead?

This immediately gives rise to a difficulty -- or at any rate, another decision. The mapping between HSV and RGB is not [bijective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection); in particular, **black**, which happens to be one of our three data points, is a single point in RGB space but occupies a whole plane in HSV. We cannot interpolate between a point and a plane, so we need to pick one specific HSV black point to go to.

This is the basis of Patrick's ingenious solution, in which H and S are specifically chosen to make the whole colour gradient linear. The result looks something like this:

[image: Patrick's linear inter/extrapolation in HSV]

This looks a lot prettier and more colourful than the previous attempts, but there are a few things we might quibble with.

One important issue is that in the case of V, where we still have definite data at all three points, those data are not actually linear, and so the linear fit is only an approximation. What this means is that the value we see here at 0.3 is not quite what it should be.

Another, to my mind bigger, quibble: **where is all that blue coming from?** All three of our known RGB data points have B=0. It seems a bit strange to suddenly introduce a whole bunch of blue for which we seem to have no evidence at all. Check out this graph of the RGB components in Patrick's HSV interpolation:

[image: Graph of the RGB components in Patrick's version]

The reason for the blue is, of course, that in switching colour spaces we have specifically selected a model where if you keep on going from green you inevitably get to blue. At the same time, we have had to discard one of our hue data points, and have chosen to fill it in by linear *extrapolation* from the other two, which means we *do* just keep on going, from green to blue to over the hills and far away.

Once again, this isn't invalid, and we might have a good reason for doing it this way. But to my mind it's a little but more out there than the previous piecewise-linear example, because of that extrapolation.

So is this the only way to do it in HSV? Of course not. There are *always* more choices.

For example, instead of choosing H and S values at 1.0 to maximise linearity, how about we instead choose them to minimise change in a *piecewise* linear interpolation? As it happens, for S the two strategies coincide: it is 100 at both points, so we make it 100 at the end too. The two segments are collinear. For H, though, we just keep it the same over the second segment. This gives a result like this:

[image: Piecewise linear interpolation in HSV]

This is not quite as cute as the previous one, but it seems slightly more plausible to me. Once again, though, that's largely an aesthetic judgement. That doesn't make this the "right" answer, anymore than it makes Patrick's or any of the others "wrong". As I said way back at the start, there is no "right" answer. It's all a matter of making choices according to your needs in a particular problem -- and being aware that you have made those choices and how they affect your outcome.

Comment: Wow, very very very interesting.  Can't I give you a +5 for this one?

Comment: @Patrick Thanks. Like I said, procrastination material :) I suppose I really ought to knuckle down and do some proper work now...

Answer (score 8):

Try to convert this to another color-representation, e.g. HSV (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV).

- Color A has a Hue of 0, a Saturation of 1 and a Value of 1.
- Color C has a Hue of ?, a Saturation of ? and a Value of 0.

? means that it actually doesn't matter (since color C is simply black).

Now also convert color B to an HSV (can't do this out of my head, sorry), then choose nice values for the Hue and Saturation of color C so that the Hue, Value and Saturation are on one line in the HSV space.  Then deduct the color at 0.7 from it.

**EDIT:** Using the RGB-HSV calculator at http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgcolorsel4.html I calculated the following:

- Color A: H:   0, V: 100, S: 100
- Color B: H: 113, V: 100, S:  63

Now we calculate the H and V of color C like this:

- H: 113/0.3 = 376.6
- V: 100 (since both A and B have a V or 100)

This gives us for the color at 0.7:

- H = 376.66*0.7 = 263.66
- V = 100
- S = somewhere around 30

Unfortunately, this doesn't fit completely for the Saturation, but if you interpolate this way, you will get something that's very close to what you want.

Comment: The colors in the example have totally different hues, so I doubt that it's a color space issue. Good thought, though.

Comment: I don't think that's true Mark.  Since color C is completely black, it's Hue is undefined, so you can choose whatever you want as Hue, and therefore make sure that they're lined up.  Same for Saturation.

Comment: That's not true for V, though. Unless B happens to have V=0.7 you still have to do a non-linear fit. And linearly extrapolating H from the first 30% of the line could easily push you through a bunch essentially spurious colour changes on the way to black.

Comment: As indeed your results demonstrate. H at 0.7 has already more than run the gamut. And how does V = 100->100->100->0 count as any kind of interpolation at all?

Comment: The V=100->100->100->0 was a typing error.  I corrected it.
For the rest, the interpolation is quite close (but not perfect, I admit)

Comment: @Patrick: on the typing error, your Vs and Ss are still mixed up. With the correct values you can indeed make S=100 and I'll even accept V~30 since the error is not too bad in this case. But the hue extrapolation is still silly. You're proposing on the basis of *two* data points that the whole line must do a turn and a half around the colour wheel? I've done a rouch matlab mockup [here](http://walkytalky.net/extern/colors.png). That's not *fitting* the data, it's outright making it up.

Comment: @WalkTalky, +1 for the nice colored bar.  Isn't fitting just making it up?  I tried to do an almost-linear fitting of the 3 points.  As Hans Passant points out in his comment on the question, it might be better to use a parabola (but given these numbers, the parabola will be almost linear in the HSV space).  You could also use a parabola in other color-representations (RGB, CYMK), you have many alternative ways of interpolating colors, just like you can interpolate in a 2-dimensional space using XY coordinates or polar coordinates. Is that making it up? Or just looking at viable alternatives?

Comment: @Patrick: I absolutely agree about looking at viable alternatives, and I know you were just presenting one possible solution. However, when there is no "right" answer it is necessary to look at the consequences of whatever "wrong" answer you choose. In this case, you and others imply that doing it in HSV is the only natural choice, when it is arguably quite unnatural here. And your solution takes advantage of the fact that the problem is even less well-posed in HSV than RGB, giving greater freedom to invent while imposing a lot of structure that isn't justified by the problem specification.

Comment: (In case it isn't clear, I really am not trying to badmouth your answer, which is a smart and honest attempt to solve the problem and help the questioner. If I get the time I may post an expanded answer of my own, but only because I think it's an interesting problem that merits discussion. And because it's great procrastination material!)

Comment: @WalkyTalky, no problem.  As long as we can help each other, every input is good.

Answer (score 4):

In the abstract, you're asking for the value of f(0.7) given that f(0.0) = (255, 0, 0), f(0.3) = (20, 160, 0), and f(1.0) = (0, 0, 0). As stated, this isn't well-defined as f could be any of an infinite number of functions.

Some possible choices for f are:

1. A series of line segments in RGB space
2. A series of line segments after mapping to HSV or HSL space
3. A cubic spline in RGB space.
4. A cubic spline in HSV/L space.

But the particular choice of how f should be defined should depend on what you're doing, or how the color stops are defined for your application.

Comment: 3 points don't fully define a cubic. you could interpolate with a quadratic spline though.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to interpolate RGB is to correct for gamma first, making the color components linear, perform an interpolation, and then convert back.  Otherwise you will get errors due to the values being nonlinear.   See http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/gamma.html for more information (although the article is about scaling, scaling is usually done by interpolating pixel values).

If you have sRGB values, you can convert between linear and nonlinear using the formulas here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB (use the Csrgb and Clinear formulas)

On the other hand, the errors are not huge, so it depends on your application if they matter.

For the interpolation itself, simple linear interpolation should suffice (as others here have noted).  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation for the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to interpolate in the wrong color space. First convert to HSV, then your colors become

```
RGB -> HSV
255,0,0 -> 0, 255,255
20,160,0 -> 80,255,160
0,0,0 -> 0,255,0
```

so its still confusing but at least we can see that the V value is interpolating to zero, the H value is confusing, but after realizing that [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) is modeled as a cylinder, we can see that it is really just interpolating from 0 to 256 mod 256, so it just goes back to zero.

so your equation would be (in HSV)

```
nH = frac*256 mod 256
nS = 255
nV =  (1-frac)*255
```

So if you substitute 0.7 for frac you will get the right calculation in HSV coordinates, if you need to go back to RGB you should see if your libraries provide such a feature (i know java's Color class supports this), but if not you can just grab the code from [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCAQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcoecsl.ece.uiuc.edu%2Fge423%2Fspring05%2Fgroup8%2FFinalProject%2FHSV_writeup.pdf&ei=DikRTJHLKMjyngeC0-DcCA&usg=AFQjCNFEO1qLDuQeuQY8uvWbyqqX3S5QiA&sig2=Z4x-y8BLvxC7Ozvf6vx28Q).  it shows how to do color space conversions in C.

Good luck